# Maximization under Kronecker product vectors

Tags: optimization, kronecker-product

I need some hints to solve the optimization problem on $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{c}
\text{max} \hspace{4mm} (\mathbf{x}\otimes \mathbf{y})^TA(\mathbf{x}\otimes \mathbf{y})\\
s.t \hspace{10mm}\|\mathbf{x}\|_2 = 1 \\
 \hspace{17mm}\|\mathbf{y}\|_2 = 1,
\end{array}
\end{equation} where $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{m}$ and $\mathbf{y} \in \mathbb{R}^{n}.$ The matrix $A$ is a rank-one symmetric matrix given by $A = \mathbf{v} \mathbf{v}^{T},$ where   $\mathbf{v} \in \mathbb{R}^{mn}.$

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, note that for any two equal-size vectors $v,w$, $w^T(vv^T)w=(w^Tv)^2$.
Subdivide $v$ into $n\times 1$ blocks $v^{(i)}$, $i=1,2,\dots, m$. Then
$$(x\otimes y)^Tv = \sum_{i=1}^m x_iy^Tv^{(i)} = y^T \sum_{i=1}^m x_i v^{(i)} = y^TVx$$
where $V\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ collects the vectors $v^{(i)}$ into columns.
The problem becomes
$$\max_{\|x\|_2=1,\|y\|_2=1} (x\otimes y)^TA(x\otimes y) = 
\max_{\|x\|_2=1,\|y\|_2=1} \left( y^T Vx \right)^2 \qquad (*)$$ 
But $\max_{\|y\|_2=1} y^Tw = \|w\|_2$ and $\max_{\|y\|_2=1} (y^Tw)^2 = \|w\|_2^2$, so
$$\max_{\|x\|_2=1,\|y\|_2=1} (x\otimes y)^TA(x\otimes y) = 
\max_{\|x\|_2=1} \left\| Vx \right\|_2^2 = \sigma_1(V)^2
$$
where $\sigma_1(V)$ is the largest singular value of $V$. The maximizing $x$ is any right-singular vector associated with $\sigma_1(V)$, and the corresponding maximizing $y$ is $y=\pm (\sigma_1(V))^{-1} Vx$, which is a corresponding *left* singular vector of $V$. In hindsight, I could have jumped right to the answer after (*).

Comment: +1 Thank you very much, Michael! Just a typo: I think a square is missing in $(y^Tw)^{\color{red}2} = \|w\|^2_2$.

Comment: Corrected! Thanks for catching it

Comment: I just realized you were asking for hints! Oops :-)

Comment: Yeah! But when you suggested the transformation on $V$, I got it. :)